# Yodlee API not returning transactions

Tags: yodlee

I am facing problem getting transactions from yodlee

Following endpoint doesnt responsd with transactions
`GET /{cobrandName}/v1/transactions`

I am using test account for developer and have connected actual bank accounts using yodlee fastlink.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **Get Transactions** API, please use the **fromDate** and **toDate** filter.
As this API will return last 30 days of transactions by default.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Krithik

Comment: I would consider this behavior a bug because I would expect it to return an empty list if it doesn't have any transactions for the last 30 days. What it actually returns is an empty JSON object {}. The same is true for the transaction count call.

Comment: This is our API behavior.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It was my mistake, i was providing incorrect login info.